# Subtract single largest number from multiple specific columns in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, min

I have a comma delimited file that looks like

```
R,F,TE,K,G,R
1,0,12,f,1,18
2,1,17,t, ,17
3,1,  , ,1,
4,0,15, ,0,16
```

There are some items which are missing, also first row is the header which I want to ignore. I wanted to calculate the second smallest number in specific columns and subtract it from all the elements in that column unless the value in the column is the minimum value. In this example, I want to subtract the second minimum values from columns 3 and 6 in the example. So, my final values would be:

```
R,F,TE,K,G,R
1,0,12,f,1,1
2,1, 2,t, ,0
3,1, , ,0,
4,0, 0, ,0,16
```

I tried individually using single columns and giving hand-coded thresholds to make it second largest by

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","; 
};
{ min=1000000; 
 if($3<min && $3 != "" && $3>12) min = $3; 
 if($3>0) $3 = $3-min+1;
 print}
 END{print min}
 ' try1.txt
```

It finds the min alright but the output is not as expected. There should be an easier way in awk.

Comment: You want to subtract the 2nd smallest number from each value, unless the value is the smallest, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN{
    FS=OFS=","
}
{
    if(NR==1){print;next}
    if(+$3)a[NR]=$3
    if(+$6)b[NR]=$6
    s[NR]=$0
}
END{
    asort(a,c)
    asort(b,d)
    for(i=2;i<=NR;i++){
        split(s[i],t)
        if(t[3]!=c[1]&&+t[3]!=0)t[3]=t[3]-c[2]
        if(t[6]!=d[1]&&+t[6]!=0)t[6]=t[6]-d[2]
        print t[1],t[2],t[3],t[4],t[5],t[6]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I want to subtract the second minimum number, not the smallest one. Also, it does not work when there are some values missing. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: test again? @lovedynasty

Comment: Since you are checking for zeros, the it does not work when there are zeros. Any workaround for those cases?

Answer (score 2):

I'd loop over the file twice, once to find the minima, once to adjust the values. It's a trade-off of time versus memory.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == 1    {min3 = $3; min6 = $6} 
    NR == FNR  {if ($3 < min3) min3 = $3; if ($6 < min6) min6 = $6; next}
    $3 != min3 {$3 -= min3}
    $6 != min6 {$6 -= min6}
    {print}
' try1.txt try1.txt
```

For prettier output:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
    NR == 1    {min3 = $3; min6 = $6; next}
    NR == FNR  {if ($3 < min3) min3 = $3; if ($6 < min6) min6 = $6; next}
    FNR == 1   {len3 = length("" min3); len6 = length("" min6)}
    $3 != min3 {$3 = sprintf("%*d", len3, $3-min3)}
    $6 != min6 {$6 = sprintf("%*d", len6, $6-min6)}
    {print}
' try1.txt try1.txt
```

---

Given the new requirements:

```
min2_3=$(cut -d, -f3 try1.txt | tail -n +2 | sort -n | grep -v '^ *$' | sed -n '2p')
min2_6=$(cut -d, -f6 try1.txt | tail -n +2 | sort -n | grep -v '^ *$' | sed -n '2p')

awk -F, -v OFS=, -v min2_3=$min2_3 -v min2_6=$min2_6 '
    NR==1 {print; next}
    $3 !~ /^ *$/ && $3 >= min2_3 {$3 -= min2_3}
    $6 !~ /^ *$/ && $6 >= min2_6 {$6 -= min2_6}
    {print}
' try1.txt
```

```
R,F,TE,K,G,R
1,0,12,f,1,1
2,1,2,t, ,0
3,1,  , ,1,
4,0,0, ,0,16
```

Comment: Thanks! I've upvoted. But this does not seem to work when some values are missing. I have updated the question accordingly. Sorry that it wasn't asked upfront!